# Facebook App Login Remember Session

Tags: php, facebook, session

I am using the following code in my PHP to login with Facebook App and each time I close the browser and re-open it, I need to re-login again. Is there anyway I can remember the login session so that I will be logged in until I hit logout.

Thanks

**Code:**

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'     =>  $appID,
        'secret'    => $appSecret,
        ));
//get the user facebook id      
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if($user){

    try{
        //get the facebook user profile data
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        $params = array('next' => $base_url.'logout.php');
        //logout url
        $logout =$facebook->getLogoutUrl($params);
        $_SESSION['User']=$user_profile;
        $_SESSION['logout']=$logout;
    }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
        error_log($e);
        $user = NULL;
    }       
}

if(empty($user)){
//login url 
$loginurl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                'scope'         => 'email,read_stream, publish_stream, user_birthday, user_location, user_work_history, user_hometown, user_photos',
                'redirect_uri'  => $base_url.'login.php',
                'display'=>'popup'
                ));


header('Location: '.$loginurl);
```

Comment: consider using the new php sdk. here´s a tutorial: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-php-sdk-4-0-tutorial/

Comment: I'm still using the _Facebook SDK 3.x.x_ since it requires _PHP 5.2_. The _SDK 4.0_ requires _PHP 5.4_, no? it seems it's too high at the moment..

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this? I'm using it about the same way and never had session problems.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'     =>  $appID,
    'secret'    => $appSecret,
    'cookie'    => TRUE                <----
));
```

**UPDATE**

Facebook set into session something like the following. Do you have such this?

```
[fb_somenumber_code] => GIBBERISH
[fb_somenumber_access_token] => SOME LONG STRING
[fb_somenumber_user_id] => YOUR API ID
```

Comment: Strange. Did you tried full reload with `Ctrl-F5` as well after the change? check my edited post for seeing what you should see in your `$_SESSION` array that comes from facebook.

Answer (score 0):

I think facebook uses cookies to keep your session open. I know this sounds stupid, but do you enable the "remember me" checkbox on login ?

If you do, your PHP should have $user with `getUser()`. I think.